# Magento 2.3.5-p2: Configurable products not saving on Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, configurable-product

I am trying to edit a few configurable products from admin but when I click on the save button nothing happens.

No errors or logs are generated either.

Anyone help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say “nothing happens” so you mean literally nothing happens (If so take a look at the browser console logs that will give you an idea of what’s going on)? Does the page reload and and it shows the old product data or does it show the changes you made and it’s just not showing on the front-end? Do any of the caches show as invalidated?

Comment: Nothing on browser logs. The page does not reload either. Do any of the caches show as invalidated: No. When I click on the Save button literally nothing happens.

Comment: check console errors or there should be some validation that due to some module override didn't show up.

Comment: I have checked the console as well, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification from you comment I suspect that there is some form validation failing on the page. Sadly clicking `save` does not auto-scroll to the error in question. Scroll down through each section of the page looking for any red text. If there are any sections with a pencil icon that means there are unsaved changes there so it may be worth opening them up as well in case the error is hidden.

Comment: Already done that. Coundnt find any form validation fails on the page.